# How to alter multiple .csv files in R

Tags: r

I have a files key which has a column of original participant ID’s (on the left) and a column of new ID’s (on the right). This is 20 rows long, and looks a bit like below:

| old_ID | new_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 975hghcc7919800014a | 10 |
| 9dbu5yg813b0c00049z | 11 |
| 9poy9aa75e2110006ci | 18 |
| 92si5gh59fd27d90009p | 20 |
| (...) | (...) |

I also have a folder of .csv files from a task which are currently labelled with the old ID codes followed by the word ‘data’, and I would like to rename these files with the new ID codes using the files key. Within each .csv file, there is also a column called ‘ppt’ which has the old ID code which I would also like to be renamed the new ID code.

So, for example, I would like ‘975hghcc7919800014adata.csv’ to be renamed ‘10data.csv’ and in the 'ppt' column to say '10' instead of ‘975hghcc7919800014a'. And then so on with the rest of the .csv files guided by the files key...

I have put together the below code, but this does not run. Can anyone help?

```
key <- read.csv("files_key.csv")

sapply(1:key$new_ID, function(i){
  # read file
  x <- read.csv(files[i])
  # change participant code to new_ID
  x$ppt <- i
  write.csv(x, paste0(dirname(files[i]), "/", i, "data.csv"), row.names = F, na = "")
  
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code with `Map` -

```
key <- read.csv("files_key.csv")

Map(function(x, y) {
  tmp <- read.csv(paste0(x, "data.csv"))
  tmp$ppt <- y
  write.csv(tmp, paste0(y, "data.csv"), row.names = FALSE, na = "")
}, key$old_ID, key$new_ID)
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked :) I hadn't come across Map yet, how does this work?

Comment: `Map` is like a loop where it passes values of `old_ID` and `new_ID` in parallel. For first iteration `x` would be `key$old_ID[1]` and `y` would be `key$new_ID[1]` , for second iteration it will pass second value of old Id and new Id and so on.